# Exception thrown on combobox selectionchanged in winform exe, works fine in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a winform application written in c#. On one of the forms, there is a combobox named 'Researcher Name'. It is data bound using tableadapters from a MS Access table named 'Researcher Info' which has two columns 'Researcher Name' and 'Researcher Age'. Researcher Name is the primary key.

When running the the exe file created, on selecting any value in this combo box (only selecting, there is no db read/write happening here, and I have no code except making a button visible that runs on the selection changed event), it throws the exception below saying that the selected combobox item is already present. Funny thing is that I am only selecting a value and not anyway entering value in the db.

[image]

But it works fine in the Visual Studio debug mode. i.e: no exceptions are thrown on doing the same thing..

There is not much code to show for this particular activity, however here goes:

> //On page load, table adapter populates combo box

```
private void editstaffdetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     this.researcher_InfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.research_Log_DatabaseDataSet1.Researcher_Info);

  researcher_NameComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

  Delete_btn.Visible = false;
  Update_btn.Visible = false;
}

 private void researcher_NameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   try
   { 
     Update_btn.Visible = true;
     Delete_btn.Visible = true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
   }
 }
```

Here is the code for the Fill method of the table adapter, it is the default generated one.

this.researcher_InfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.research_Log_DatabaseDataSet1.Researcher_Info);

> public virtual int
>   Fill(Research_Log_DatabaseDataSet1.Researcher_InfoDataTable dataTable)
>
> {
>
> this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
>
> ```
>         if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true)) 
>
>         {  dataTable.Clear();  }
>
>         int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
>         return returnValue; }
> ```

Here is the exception stack trace:

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'Researcher Name' is
>   constrained to be unique.  Value 'Kwek Gwen' is already present.
>   at System.Data.UniqueConstraint.CheckConstraint(DataRow row,
>   DataRowAction action)
>   at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args,
>   DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
>   at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32
>   proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Int32
>   position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
>   at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecord(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord,
>   DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean fireEvent)
>   at System.Data.DataRow.SetNewRecord(Int32 record)
>   at System.Data.DataRow.EndEdit()
>   at System.Data.DataRowView.EndEdit() 
>   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32
>   newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean
>   firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position(Int32 value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

And here is what the debug output window shows, with all exceptions enabled during the combobox click event

> The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x15f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Users\jollyk\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Release\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe',
>   Symbols loaded.
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread '' (0x1248) has exited
>   with code 0 (0x0). The thread '' (0xd84) has exited with code
>   0 (0x0). Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged' Step into:
>   Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback' Step into:
>   Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal' Step into:
>   Stepping over non-user code 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc' Step into: Stepping over
>   non-user code 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc' Step into: Stepping
>   over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback' Step into:
>   Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc' Step into: Stepping
>   over non-user code 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand' Step into:
>   Stepping over non-user code 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc' Step into: Stepping over
>   non-user code 'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop'

Any help appreciated.

Comment: pasting code can help

Comment: Show some code please?
It looks like you are trying to add a value to a column that can only accepts unique values, so there might be something wrong in filling your data

Comment: I have added code for the form load event and the combobox selectionchanged event,

Comment: @KendeJong: I am only selecting a value in the combobox, there is no addition taking place anywhere, atleast not to my knowledge.

Comment: Please click the "Details" button and post here the full stack trace of the exception, as text if possible otherwise as screenshot.

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: Stack Trace added. And I am not sure why it is not throwing an exception in the debug mode. but only in the exe.

Comment: Show this code - `table adapter populates combo box` - do you have update command associated with this table adapter?

Comment: I use data binding from the UI and in the code behind the tableadapter.fill method populates the combobox. Update command for table adapter is just the default generated one: public virtual int Update(Research_Log_DatabaseDataSet1.Researcher_InfoDataTable dataTable) {
            return this.Adapter.Update(dataTable);
        }

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the table adapter and created a new one, and now it works. Did not however manage to figure out what was wrong with the first. I am done with table adapters, next time i write code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Stack Trace, when you change the Combobox selection it's (apparently) causing a change to the row in the dataset, and the data binding is attempting to repopulate the Combobox row accordingly. So maybe you have a property of the Combobox set to re-validate the data on selection, or perhaps the data binding object is re-validating when the selection changes?

Comment: Well, but why would this not throw an error in the debug mode then...

Comment: Are you certain it isn't?  Inspect your debug output window to be sure that it's not silent.  Sometimes an error that is thrown visually in Release is not in Debug...it only appears as an exception logged to output.

Comment: @learn_code do you have thrown Exceptions enabled? `Debug->Exceptions`-ensure 'Thrown' is ticked for CLR exceptions

Comment: @DonBoitnott: I didn't find anything suspicious in the debug o/p window, but I may be wrong so I have added the contents above.

Comment: @wal Yep exceptions are enabled. Have added the debug o/p window contents to the question.